# Geocode Service Request

Tags: javascript, geocode, nominatim

I'm a beginner with JS and I'm confused with all of these tutorials I have seen about my problem and I don't know how to solve it. So I need to check if the city input from a user is valid via the Nominatim OSM geocode service and I need to make a request so I get a JSON answer.

On HTML I have created a div class for town input etc.

I have seen a tutorial on YT and I have this on JS:

```
function geocode() {
        let location = '22 Main st Boston MA';
        axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
            params: {
                address: location,
                key: 'AIzaSyAtsq1bTSxda8ulMA2oVJhIjOZGE2iAXuY'
            }
        })
            .then(function (respone) {
                console.log(respone);
                console.log(response.data.results[0].formatted_address);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
}
```

Of course, this is not the solution I need. I just want to test if it works but I get an error: "Billing Cloud" etc. so I need some help or a good tutorial on how to solve it.

EDIT: error_message "You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started".
I should get info about the location variable.

Comment: forgot to mention i have linked the <script for axios.

Comment: Post your full error! People can't help you if they don't know what's wrong.